# Return indexes of longest batches of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe that's ordered by two columns : 'ID' and a date column.
There's a significant amount of missing values in that table and what I'm interested in is understanding how the missing values are distributed : are they mainly concentrated for one 'ID', do all IDs have missing values in their start for example (date wise), are missing values unrelated etc.

After a groupby ID + count of missing values, I used missingno package and it proved to be useful, this is the result I got (sanitizing column names) : [image: missingno]

From the picture, it seems like there are specific batches of rows where most columns are missing.
If you look at the arrow for example, I can probably ballpark a value for indexes to search (~idx = 750000) but this wouldn't be practical since there are other instances with the same thing happening.
What I would like to have is a function `batches_missing(cols, n_rows)` that takes a list of columns and and an int `n_rows` and returns a list of tuples [(index_start_batch1, index_end_batch1), ...] of all batches where the given columns have more than n_rows consecutive rows of missing values.

With a mock example :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'col2':[9, 7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'col3':[11, 12, 13, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 1, 2, 3]})
```

`batches_missing(['col1','col2'] , 3)` would return `[(2,5),(8,10)]`

Can this be done efficiently given that the actual data is pretty big (1 mil rows) ? I would also be very interested in hearing about other ways of analyzing missing data so would appreciate any reading materials / links !

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a minimal reproducible example and explaining that I'm also interested in discussing what other potential ways are there to explore missing data beyond simple counts / percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tally row wise to see which rows are all NAs, given selected columns:

```
rowwise_tally = df[['col1','col2']].isna().apply(all,axis=1)

0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
```

Now you can group this runs:

```
grp = rowwise_tally.diff().cumsum().fillna(0)
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
```

Then count the number of nas in each group and also get the start and end:

```
na_counts = rowwise_tally.groupby(grp).sum()
pos = pd.Series(np.arange(len(df))).groupby(grp).agg([np.min, np.max])
pos[na_counts>=3].to_numpy()

array([[ 2,  5],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

There might be a better way to get the position instead of using pd.Series like I did. For now, wrap this into a function:

```
def fun(data,cols,minlen):
    rowwise_tally = data[cols].isna().apply(all,axis=1)
    grp = rowwise_tally.diff().cumsum().fillna(0)
    na_counts = rowwise_tally.groupby(grp).sum()
    pos = pd.Series(np.arange(len(data))).groupby(grp).agg([np.min, np.max])
    return pos[na_counts>=minlen].to_numpy()

fun(df,['col1','col2'],3)
```